# Is there a way to optimise for m out of n variables?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a (Portfolio Optimization) python program that uses scipy to optimize n variables using constraints. However, I was wondering if it is possible to tell the program to choose m out of these n variables that will be the best for maximsing the objective?

This is my current code:

```
def obj(x):
    return (-np.sum(array_weights.t*x))
def con_vol(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))
```

where array_returns is list of returns for all the stocks that is imported from Bloomberg and cov_matrix is the covariance matrix constructed using the returns data.

```
cons = [{'type':'eq','fun':lambda x: np.sum(x)-1}, {'type':'ineq','fun':lambda x: con_vol}\

bnds = tuple(0.02, 0.1) for x in range(20)

opts = sco.minimize(obj, list_final_weights, bounds = bnds, method = 'SLQSP', constraints = cons)
```

In this program weights are allocated to all the assets. I want a way in which it can choose (say the best 10 to allocate to out of 20)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to solve this problem iteratively (running the `scipy` solver many times):

1st iteration: run the `scipy` solver, take the solution, and discard all of the `n` variables the coefficients of which are below a certain (initially rather small) threshold `t`.

Next iteration: run the `scipy` solver again, now not searching within the space of the previously discarded variables anymore. With a (slighlty) increased value of `t`, now discard further variables.

Repeat this until only `m` variables left.

There are also more sophisticated approaches involving e.g. genetic programming techniques to identify relevant parameters or even functional forms (so-called sparse symbolic regression in the latter case, see e.g. a `python` implementation here: https://github.com/snagcliffs/PDE-FIND.